# Class vs Instance Scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, singleton, es6-class, monostate

I am evaluating a way of use the Singleton Pattern called Monostate in JavaScript.

I have some code like the following:

```
class Boss {
  get name() { return Boss._name }
  set name(value) {
    Boss._name = value;
  }

  get age() { return Boss._age }
  set age(value) {
    Boss._age = value
  }

  toString() {
    return `
      Boss' name is ${this.name}
      and he is ${this.age} years old.
    `
  }
}

Boss._age = undefined;
Boss._name = undefined;
```

But I am not deeply understanding the difference between the Class scope vs the Instance scope

I mean if I make the following:

```
let boss = new Boss();
boss.name = 'Bob';
boss.age = 55;

let boss2 = new Boss();
boss2.name = 'Tom';
boss2.age = 33;

console.log(boss.toString());
console.log(boss2.toString());
```

I will always get the data of the second instance with name `Tom`, but why?

```
Boss' name is Tom and he is 33 years old.
```

Comment: you failed to find answer because (iirc) there is no `Class scope` and `Instance scope` in javascript. search for prototype / inheritance for better understand. (I believe there is a duplicate, but I cannot find it now)

Comment: and what is `I will always get the first instance with name Bob` mean?

Comment: `I will always get the first instance with name Bob, but why?`  That's strange, I would have expected you always get Tom..

Comment: Yeah, for example if we make a function inside boss that prints `name` and `age` as a result you will always obtain the data of the first instance `boss` -> `Bob` and `55`
Let me add that function to the code and please try it

Comment: @Keith you are right, I am getting Tom data. A bad note, but I am lossing the Bob information

Comment: Yes you will, because your assigning to a `global` value `Boss`,  in some respects assigning properties to `Boss` would be no different to say assigning to a global var called `bossStatic`..   If you don't use `this`, it's not assigning to an instance of anything.

Comment: That's the point of Monostate. Instances don't get their own data; data is stored on the class (`Boss`) instead. There is only one class, so there is only one set of data that is shared between all instances.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks Keith and Paulpro, do you suggest any documentation about it?

Comment: This is exactly the reason why you should avoid the global-state singleton pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this behaviour happens is due the fact that instances of `Boss` refer to the same `Boss` object to set and read their values. Instances of `Boss` set the `_name` and `_age` value on `Boss`. When reading from these instance attributes, the last value set is returned.

You can see this by the value of `Boss._name` that changes every time a an instance of `Boss` sets their name. After `boss.name = 'Bob'` the value of `Boss._name` will be `'Bob'`. After setting `boss2.name = 'Tom'` the value of `Boss._name` will be `'Tom'`.

I've added a snippet that hopefully displays the troubling behaviour better. In the scenario below `boss1` and `boss2` have their own storage while `boss3` and `boss4` share their storage (you use the `Boss` object as storage).

```js
class Boss {
  constructor(storage) {
    this.storage = storage || {};
  }
  
  get name() {
    return this.storage.name;
  }
  
  set name(value) {
    this.storage.name = value;
  }
}

var boss1 = new Boss(),
    boss2 = new Boss(),
    sharedStorage = {},
    boss3 = new Boss(sharedStorage),
    boss4 = new Boss(sharedStorage);

boss1.name = "a";
boss2.name = "b";
boss3.name = "c";
boss4.name = "d";

console.log(boss1.name, boss2.name, boss3.name, boss4.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Boss` doesn't refer to instance of class it will refer to the constructor function `Boss` which is only one in the whole code. In the methods you are adding property not to the instance but the constructor.

You need to use `this` to access the instance inside the method of an object.

```js
class Boss {
  get name() { return this._name }
  set name(value) {
    this._name = value;
  }

  get age() { return this._age }
  set age(value) {
    this._age = value
  }
}


let boss = new Boss();
boss.name = 'Bob';
boss.age = 55;

let boss2 = new Boss();
boss2.name = 'Tom';
boss2.age = 33;


console.log(boss2.name);

console.log(boss.name);
```

Comment: This just makes each instance of Boss have its own `name` and `age`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) instead of the class name `Boss` to refer to the object instance from within the class definition:

```js
class Boss {
  get name() {
    return this._name
  }
  set name(value) {
    this._name = value;
  }

  get age() {
    return this._age
  }
  set age(value) {
    this._age = value
  }

  toString() {
    return `
      Boss' name is ${this.name}
      and he is ${this.age} years old.
    `
  }
}

const b1 = new Boss();
b1.name = 'Tom';
b1.age = 55;

const b2 = new Boss();
b2.name = 'Bill';
b2.age = 33;

console.log(b1.toString());
console.log(b2.toString());
```

The `Boss` you are referring to in your code is actually the constructor when you really want the instance.